Distribution of gaps between observations in a specified window
I encountered something that looks like an interesting probability problem and was wondering if it (or something similar) has a known solution. Pointers on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated too.
Suppose we have a source that emits 0's most of the time, and it sometimes emits 1's after periods of time, which are independent and have a binomial distribution $B(n, p)$. We observe the source for a fixed duration of time $w$ and we get a sequence of 0's and 1's. Here is a sample for $B(250, 0.25)$ and window $w=250$.

In general, it is possible that typical times between emissions of 1's are longer than the window, so it appeared reasonable to somehow deal with the window boundaries. Two options are proposed:

treat boundaries as if they have 1's,
or treat them as periodic, i.e. compute an additional gap between the last and firs observations.

Is it possible to find the distribution of gaps between 1's in either of the cases above? I tried simulating the distributions using $B(250, 0.25)$ and window $w=250$, (see Python code snippet below), got something that looks very cool, but failed to even get started with an analytical solution as this feels way out of my depth...

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom

n, p = 250, 0.25
rv = binom(n, p)

w = 250
w_bins = 150
N = 1_000_000
N_w = int(N/w)

N_s = int(1.1*N/(n*p))

x = np.arange(0, w)
rv_pmf = rv.pmf(x)

events = rv.rvs(N_s).cumsum()
events = events[events < N]

sample = np.zeros(N)
sample[events] = 1
sample = sample.reshape(N_w, w)

gaps = []
gaps_periodic= []
for i in range(N_w):
    sample_slice = np.where(sample[i, :] == 1)[0]
    gaps.append(
        np.append(
            sample_slice[1:] - sample_slice[:-1],
            ((w-sample_slice[-1]), sample_slice[0])
        )
    )
    gaps_periodic.append(
        np.append(
            sample_slice[1:] - sample_slice[:-1],
            (w-sample_slice[-1]) + sample_slice[0]
        )
    )

